# where is the physical location of a distributed partitioned view?

Tags: sql-server, database, scale, scaling, database-partitioning

I cannot understand **distributed partitioned views** (database scaling)

The tutorials that I've read always have this sort of image. [User]s => [Distributed partitioned view] and from [Distributed partitioned view] there will be many arrows pointing to each individual servers.

Where exactly does the distributed partitioned view live at? Does it live in a separate server dedicated to the job?

Answer (score 2):

A distributed partitioned view resides wherever you create it. Any view is always created on a particular server. "Distributed" just means a view referencing tables which happen to exist on other servers.